# simple input form width not being changed by css

Tags: html, css

I have a simple  html element that i apply this css

```
width: 600px
```

[But as you see on jsfiddle, it has no effect](http://jsfiddle.net/gdwSX/68/). I dont know why its width not responding

Here is the html

```
<input id="title" type="text" maxlength="300" id="ask_title_edit">
```

here is the css

```
#ask_title_edit
{
    width: 1610px;
}
```

Comment: I think I don't see any input type text anywhere in the fiddle and you are member for 3 years, we expect some code to be posted by you in your question rather than just a link

Comment: I don't see any element that has that CSS either.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Works ok for me, you've not explained the issue very well

Comment: @Mr.Alien there is an input type text

Comment: @DrDeo You pasted the wrong link then. There are no input elements in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @DrDeo You've posted some "floatObject" jsfiddle, which seems unrelated.

Comment: sorry didnt notice. let me edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please remove last title only one id can in html tag...

and check it's work

```
<input id="title" type="text" maxlength="300" >
```

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/gdwSX/67/)

Answer (score 0):

Your element has two attributes id. Use only one to make it work correctly. You can also use something like this in your CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 1610px;
}
```